# Is it possible to use activeadmin with with less css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

the [active admin docs](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) says:

```
If you are using Rails >= 3.1, you must also include a beta version of MetaSearch and sass-rails:

  # Gemfile in Rails >= 3.1
  gem 'activeadmin'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
```

I don't like sass-rails, I like less-css so can i use less instead of sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveAdmin's styles are written in SCSS. So to use the provided styles you have to install `sass-rails`.

However for your own styles you can use whatever you like. With the powers of the asset pipeline you can freely combine your custom less styles with the upstream-provided SCSS styles. As they are all compiled to CSS, your users doesn't notice an difference.